# Using "*" in string in c#

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

I want to use "*"  in a string.

I want to store in a string something like this

```
string strin="e list * "*"\r\n";
```

But visual studio shows error for this line and do not compile.
Error:

> Operator '*' cannot be applied to operands of type 'string' and 'string'

How can I use this?

Comment: On another note dont make a string variable called strin...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to escape the double quotes in your string, it would be better like this:

```
string strin="e list * \"*\"\r\n";
```

My assumption is you want a real carriage return/linefeed, not the literal "\r\n" characters, that is why I stripped the '@' symbol

Comment: If `\r\n` was meant literally, then it would have to be escaped with: `"\\r\\n"`

Answer (score 6):

The problem isn't with `*`, but with the `"` you want to also seem have in the string. They need to be escaped:

```
string strin = @"e list * ""*""\r\n";
```

**Note**: the above verbatim string literal will have the string `\r\n` embedded in it - not a windows end of line. For appending an end of line, I suggest appending [`Environment.NewLine`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.newline.aspx).

Or, if not using a verbatim string literal:

```
string strin = "e list * \"*\"" + Environment.NewLine;
```

If you don't do this, the expression `@"e list * "*"\r\n"` is interpreted as the string `"e list * "` multiplied by (`*`) by the string `"\r\n"`. Since the `*` operator is not defined on strings, you are getting the error.

Answer (score 3):

```
string strin = @"e list * "" * ""\r\n";
```

just add dbl quotes

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that you are trying to multiply two strings together which is not allowed. You would get the same error if you wrote this

```
"a"*"b"
```

which maybe makes it easier to see. Perhaps you meant to write

```
"e list * "+"\r\n"
```

As a piece of more general advice, the compiler emitted an excellent and informative message:

```
Operator '*' cannot be applied to operands of type 'string' and 'string'
```

Not all compilers produce such helpful messages, but when they do it is worth reading them carefully. This messages takes you straight to the root of the problem.

Answer (score 2):

You need to escape the `"`'s in the String Literal:

```
string strin=@"e list * ""*""\r\n";
```

When using the `@` prefix you escape them with another `"`.
Otherwise use a `\`.

Answer (score 0):

The issue isn't the *.  It's that you are terminating the string without escaping it.

Try this:

```
string strin = @"e list * ""*""\r\n";
```

Comment: Wow.. look at all the answers.  I swear there were NONE when I started typing this.  :)

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of of problems in your code.

1. The @ before the string means use the literal string and not translate the \r \n.  The @ should be removed.
2. Once you remove the the @ symbol, you will need to put slashes before any quotes that are part of your string.

   string strin = "e list * \" * \"\r\n";